# Importing data for advanced custom fields plugin?

Tags: custom-field, import, bulk-import

I have a member section built using the http://www.advancedcustomfields.com plugin. There are 300 members that each have the following data:

- Company name
- Specialism (check boxes)
- Web address
- Telephone number
- Region
- Address
- Email

What's the best way to import into the database? How should I setup a csv file? I haven't added the 300 member pages, I just have these custom fields setup using the plugin.

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. This is either a **PHP/SQL** question rather than a **WordPress** question, or else it is a *Plugin-specific* question, and thus *too localized*.

Comment: @ChipBennett ??? That's ridiculous! Exactly what forum am I supposed to ask this on then? If asked on the normal SO forum they would just send me here! There's plenty of plugin specific questions on here. Your far too agressive with modding this forum as this isn't the first time!

Comment: Fair enough. So: *what is the **WordPress** specific part of this question*? You're asking about importing an arbitrary data set into an arbitrary database, and doing so via a CSV file. None of that has anything to do with WordPress. (p.s. I'm **not** a mod.)

Comment: @ChipBennett It has EVERYTHING to do with Wordpress since I need it all in a format that's readable by the cms. So your saying the hundreds of questions on here to do with plugins are too localized and database questions aren't related. My related questions sidebar is filled with similar questions yet according to your "rules" I can't post it here! Exactly where do I post this then?

Comment: What do you mean by "*readable by the CMS*"? Are you saying that you're trying to do a raw SQL import to update the `wp_post_meta` DB table entries for 300 existing posts?

Comment: @ChipBennett I'm trying to import 300 new pages via a csv file, which just worked ok (the page title is the company name). The next part is filling in the custom fields with the data but I have no idea what to put in each field in the csv file in order to get the correct data to show on the correct member.

Comment: Two questions: 1) how did you import the static pages, and 2) why are you wanting to use a *CSV* file for import? Related: *how* are you importing? Are you using the WordPress importer via `Dashboard -> Tools -> Import`, or some other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have successfully gotten all 300 *Pages* imported based on the comments.  (Regardless of how you did it, either by using the WordPress import plugin or by using some MySQL tool like phpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro or whatever)... You have 300 pages in the `wp_posts` table.  Let's start from here then...

The ACF plugin uses the `wp_postmeta` table to populate and link custom fields to specific posts/pages.  (A very thoughtful design, by the way)!

That table consists of 4 columns:

`meta_id` - A unique auto incremented primary key

`post_id` - A foreign key that links to the post or page

`meta_key` - In this case the name (key) of the custom field

`meta_value` - The actual text or content for that custom field

So if you've created a CSV file, you would basically create your data to fit into that model.  If you have 300 records sitting in your `wp_posts` table, they should all have a unique `ID` (in the `ID` column).  That's the ID that you'll put into the `wp_postmeta.post_id` column.

Now, if you inspect the Field Group you've created, you'll see all of the Field Names (which are the `wp_postmeta.meta_key` values.  Here's a screenshot of an example in a project I'm working on right now:

[image: ACF Example]

I've named mine `header_content` and `left_sidebar_content` for example.  Finally, throw the values of each of your fields into the `wp_postmeta.meta_value` field.

All of that is a high level walkthrough of the schema and structure of the data.  The actual implementation of how **you** import the data is up to you.  (Whether you use a CSV file, XML, or actually write some SQL to insert the data).

Hope that helps get you on the right track!

Comment: can't agree the approach used by ACF is a good design or not, as the data is not easy to be searched or indexed...